# How should I respond to text being changed in a QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` populated with some `QStandardItem`s. The items are editable, and I want to program to react whenever the text of an item is changed, either by way of a signal or an event filter. I can't find anything that fills the bill. I tried `QStandardModel::itemChanged`, but that responds to changes in other item data, and I don't see a way to distinguish between changes in the text content and user data. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but note that editing text happens in `Qt::EditRole`, not in `Qt::DataRole` (default role). Maybe this hint helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with this I wound up deriving a class from QStandardItem and overriding QStandardItem::setData something like this:

```
void MyStandardItem::setData(const QVariant& value, int role)
{
    if (role == Qt::EditRole) {
        doStuff();
    }

    QStandardItem::setData(value, role);
}
```